# Wordpress Theme file editor - error with sleep() php function

Tags: php, functions, wp-admin, editor, wp-editor

I'm doing some tests by modifying my .php files directly from the wordpress theme editing interface ( **/wp-admin/theme-editor.php** ). *(to avoid lengthy deployment pipelines)*

However, as soon as I add the php function **sleep()** to my code, an error occurs and I can no longer save my file.
I should point out that this function is not disabled on our server and is fully functional.

[image]

Does anyone know why this restriction applies?
How can this error be avoided?

Thanks in advance,
Vincent